# SIM contacts do not show up in my lenovo k6

Tags: contacts, sim-card, lenovo

How to show my sim contacts in my cell phone? I want to delete my sim contacts because I have received sms by my sim contacts not google account. Contacts are displayed of google account but not showing my sim contacts.
Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go [SIMcardToolManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keesadens.SIMcardToolManager)

with this you can view, Add , delete & manage contacts